# Tap AppleEvents being sent to another application

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-carbon, appleevents

Is it possible to monitor or tap the stream of Apple Events being sent to a process, in the same way you can tap Quartz Events?

I have an application that talks to another application to force it to import files, but it does so in a way that's unavailable through menus or UI scripting, and I'm trying to track down how it does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to do this programmatically or is manual/interactive OK? If manual is OK, here are some approaches:

Try using AppleScript Editor to record the target app.

Try using the techniques listed in [Technical Note TN2124: Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html) under [Apple Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECAE). For example, set the environment variable `AEDebugReceives` to `1` and run the target app under that environment.

Comment: In this case I don't have the source or can compile either application, but I do know which application is sending.  I shall try this.

Comment: The Technote did the trick, I just launched the sending app from the terminal with AEDebugSends=1 and it spits out a transcript.  I don't need this stuff programmatically, I'm trying to reverse-engineer what these two apps are doing (the receiving app doesn't have a dictionary for this event).

Answer (score -2):

there is no such tap for ae events AFAIK *I am happy to be proven wrong*

there are NSDistributed notifications which you can tap!