# How can one view the applescript code that executes on particular application?

Tags: macos, applescript, reverse-engineering

There is one application that controls Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac using AppleScript.
It does really nice things that I want to implement in my own app.

So, is it possible to intercept AppleScript calls to particular application, and reconstruct source code of AppleScript that made that calls?

Comment: Try to open your AppleScript-App with Script-Editor. You will either see the script or get an appropriate error message.

Comment: @DigiMonk, Unfortunately, this AppleScript-App is not a compiled AppleScript it is a fully functional, cocoa application with GUI, so it couldn't be opened using AppleScript editor.

Comment: No. All you can do is 1. monitor the raw Apple events being sent to the target application for hints (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422004/tap-appleevents-being-sent-to-another-application) and develop new code to send similar commands, or 2. woo the original developer into revealing their secrets.

Comment: @foo Thanks a lot, that should be in answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to view source code of applescript that executes on particular app.

But debugging apple events, can make sense to cast a light on what is going on.

So I just opened Terminal.app and executed a command:

```
env AEDebugReceives=1 /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Word
```

That will force Microsoft Word (in fact almost any application) to print all received apple events in terminal.